# Android Sensor Accelerometer Value

Tags: android-sensors

How to use the android sensor accelerometer values? The value observed contained gravity effect. We subtract gravity from observer acceleration to get actual acceleration. Now,this acceleration value is to filter. Which one is best filter: low-pass or high-pass?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use low pass filtering to get smoother data. Low pass removes high frequency oscillations that are unlikely to be from actual movement of the device.

By the way, don't remove gravity yourself. Use Android's Linear Accelerometer option and it will remove gravity for you.

EDIT: I should have specified that low-pass is better of the two, but in reality you'll probably want to use Kalman Filtering provided that there's constraints on how the device will move.